# How to inject html tags within a script in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have a string where I would like to inject a `<br>` tag based on array values.

**My html code:**

```html
'Hello people. `<span>`Hello to everyone`</span>`'; 
<script>
    let array = ['Hello', 'to everyone'];
</script>
```

I need to inject `<br>` tag between 'Hello' and 'to everyone' inside `<span>` based on contents of array. How can I do it without replacing the tags and not affecting the first 'Hello' word?

**Expected output:**

```html
'Hello people. `<span>`Hello `<br>` to everyone`</span>`'
```

Comment: Please post your html code

Answer (score 2):

You should do this by clearing the contents of the `<span>` element, then iterate over the array with a `foreach` method where you add the contents of the array then a line break(`<br>`).You can define the line break with `const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');` , then you can  add it to the span element with some `DOM` manipulation like this `elem.appendChild(lineBreak)`

**Here is the full code:**

```html
<head>
  <title>hello world</title>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello people. <span id='message'  style="WHITE-SPACE: br">Hello to everyone</span></p>
  <script>
    function split_words(){
      let array = ['Hello', 'to everyone'];
      const elem = document.getElementById('message');
      let result = '';
      const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
      elem.innerHTML = '';
      array.forEach(word => {
        elem.innerHTML += word;
        elem.appendChild(lineBreak)
        
      });
    }
    window.onload = split_words(); 
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `\n` or `<br/>` within the text.
Your code will look something like so

```
document.write(`Hello people. <span>Hello <br> to everyone</span>`);
```